# MySQL get a conversation between two users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL table named private_messages with fields (id,from,to,message,stamp).
the stamp field corresponds to the date of the message

So what query do i need for:

1) get a conversation between two users (ordered by date)?

I have tried the query

```
(SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE from=$my_id AND to=$other_id) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE from=$other_id AND to=$my_id) 
ORDER BY stamp
;
```

but doesn't work...

2) get the last messages beetween me and other users, each one with a different user, ordered by date (to construct a inbox like in faceebook for example)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.)

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    private_messages a
WHERE   (a.from = $my_id AND a.to = $other_id) OR
        (a.from = $other_id AND a.to = $my_id)
ORDER   BY stamp DESC
```

2.)

```
SELECT  f.*
FROM
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    private_messages a
            WHERE  (LEAST(a.from, a.to), GREATEST(a.from, a.to), a.stamp) 
                    IN  (   
                            SELECT  LEAST(b.from, b.to) AS x, 
                                    GREATEST(b.from, b.to) AS y,
                                    MAX(b.stamp) AS msg_time
                            FROM    private_messages b
                            GROUP   BY x, y
                        )
        ) f
WHERE   $my_id IN (f.from, f.to)
ORDER   BY f.stamp DESC
```

Comment: It is called `ALIAS`. It is very useful especially when you have long tableNames.

Comment: answer has been updated. by the way, do you have sample records so we can play with it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM private_messages 
WHERE `to`='$my_id' OR `from`='$my_id' GROUP BY `to`, `from`) AS x 
ORDER BY x.stamp DESC ;
```

`To`, `From` could be **reserved words**. Noticed that `x` is a table alias.

Comment: @João P. Ceia give above query a try and comment please. `=)`

Comment: doesn't work as supposed because returns different messages between the same users (in the two different "directions")

Answer (score 0):

I had done this in past, but with simple query. May be this will work for you

```
      SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE (from=$my_id AND to=$other_id) OR (from=$other_id AND to=$my_id) ORDER BY stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Pretty sure you need quotes around your PHP variables, like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE from='$my_id' AND to='$other_id') UNION (SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE from='$other_id' AND to='$my_id') ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

2) Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE to='$my_id' OR from='$my_id' GROUP BY to, from) AS tmp_table ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

Comment: in your answer 2) doesn't include messages sent by "me"

Comment: query 2) gives error...
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE `to`=1 OR `from`=1 GROUP BY to, from) AS tmp_table ORDER BY stamp DESC
gives:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, from) AS tmp_table ORDER BY stamp DESC' at line 1