# Message service query on Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a problem which I've trying to solve for days and couldnt figure this out. Please Please help me if you have any idea or tip anything .
Im trying to make a messaging service on my website. There is a product and users will able to message under it.There will be 2 users at max. Not like a comment line. Here is the database schemes I made .

**ps:**

*$user1 ;* a person who login the website,

*$user2 ;* the person who posted the product

*$id ;* the id of posted product

```
>CREATE TABLE `conversation`
c_id int(11)
product_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL
user_one int(11) NOT NULL
user_two int(11) NOT NULL
time int(11) DEFAULT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
KEY `user_one`(`user_one`),
KEY `user_two` (`user_two`), 
KEY `product_id`(`product_id`)

CREATE TABLE `conversation_reply`
`cr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reply` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`user_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
`c_id_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cr_id`),
KEY `user_id_fk` (`user_id_fk`)
KEY `c_id_fk`(`c_id_fk`)

'CREATE TABLE `post`
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_post` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
`time_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`product_img` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

- post's **id** referenced to **product_id** in *conversation* table
- **user_id_fk** referenced to **id** in member's table
- **c_id** referenced to as **c_id_fk** in *conversation_reply* table

Here is the query I'm trying to do.However It doesn't properly work.

```
SELECT U.id,C.c_id,U.username,R.reply
FROM member U,conversation C, conversation_reply R,post P
WHERE 
CASE
WHEN C.user_one = '$user1' THEN C.user_two = U.id
WHEN C.user_two = '$user2' THEN C.user_one= U.id
END
AND
C.c_id=R.c_id_fk
AND
(C.user_one ='$user1' OR C.user_two ='$user2')
 AND C.product_id='$id' ORDER BY C.c_id DESC
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to elaborate more on what you mean when you say "However It doesn't properly work.".  Exactly what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Instead of that huge screenshot, could you just post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: What are `user_one` and `user_two`? Why don't you want conversations where `user_one = $user2`?

Comment: BTW, you don't need quotes around `$user1` and `$user2`, since these are integers, not strings.

Comment: @Barmar Hello, Sorry for 'huge' screenshot, as you can easily see I'm new at this.I changed the way like you said. Secondly, I'm trying to have a conversation between two user , but i couldn't  figure this out. I will change the quotes

Comment: That's totally unreadable. Please repost it, and use code formatting, not quotation.

Comment: Why are you only checking `user_one = $user1` and `user_two = $user2`? What if the logged in user is `user_two` in the conversation?

Comment: @Barmar Hey again,I changed again as you said. How can i do it ?

Comment: How can you do what? Your question need to explain clearly what you're trying to do. Which conversations do you want to display? Does it matter if `$user1` is `user_one` or `user_two` in the conversation? The same thing for `$user2`?

Comment: What you probably want is `WHERE ((user_one = $user1 AND user_two = $user2) OR (user_one = $user2 AND user_two = $user1))`

Comment: @DavidCram there is a foreach statement. If 2 people talked under same product id , I'm willing to show those conversation only those people. However, only user1 can see the post it posted itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545143/mysql-get-a-conversation-between-two-users

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry for not being clear enough , i guess im tried. Anyway. I wanna display user1's and user2's inputs only each other.to be more detailed. There is a product. And the owner of the product is user1. user2 is customer. User2 will send a private message to user1.In that way they will be started a conversion